# Число - палиндром

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, python-3.5

Новичок в Python, взялся за реализацию кода на нахождение палиндрома для числа 9009. Решил все сделать через цикл while, но код не работает так, как надо. (

Вот мой код:

```
 def is_palindrom(purpose):
     const = 0
     count = 0
     appear = 9009
     while purpose >= const:
        news = count * appear
        if news > purpose:
           break
        news = str(news)
        news2 = news[::-1]
        if news == news2 and len(str(news)) == 2 and len(str(news2)) == 2:
            print(count, appear)
       count+=1
       purpose-=1
 is_palindrom(9009)
```

Не могу разобраться, где что упустил. Могли ли бы Вы поделиться советом, как этот код доработать, или же вовсе  мне нужно его переписать? Большое спасибо за ответы!

Comment: https://pythoner.name/palindrome

Comment: Палиндром это число которое одинаково читается и слева направо и справо налево. Но у вавс какой то другой алгоритм. Может объясните подробнее по какой логике вам нужно искать ваш ответ.

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за ответ! Суть в том, что нужно найти 2 числа, произведение которых является палиндромом. У меня там все спуталось, вот я сюда за помощью и обратился)

Comment: Опять ничего не понятно. Дано число и разложить его на два множителя. А  при чем тут тогда палинром?

Comment: Есть 2 числа, произведение которых 9009 - палиндром. Нужно их найти.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import math
def is_palindrom(purpose):
    for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(purpose))):
        if purpose % i == 0:
            print(i, purpose//i)
is_palindrom(9009)
```

Comment: Да уж, спасибо большое) Новичок я еще, поэтому так ловко с кодом управляться не могу. Но у меня есть один вопрос: зачем вы извлекали корень из purpose? И зачем делили нацело на i? Не могли бы Вы мне объяснить?

Comment: Потому что если перебирать числа дальше чем значение корня то первое число будет больше второго и будут повторы. Те например подходит 3 и 3003, и если все перебирать то найдём и 3003 и 3. Поэтому дальше корня нет смысла проверять. А если число нацело на i не делиться значит i не подходит. Ведь не подойдет же 2 и 4504,5.

Answer (score 1):

Вот еще одно решение этой задачи, на мое мнение еще проще, можно просто сделать реверс строки.

```py
def is_palindrom(string):
    if str(string) == str(string)[::-1]:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: Это решение другой задачи, а не той, которую пытался решить автор вопроса. PS. нужно возращать True/False, а не 1/0. PPS. Хоть задача и не совсем такая, которую вы решаете своим кодом, но тем не менее, в вопросе речь о числе, а не о строке. PPPS. В коде синтаксическая ошибка.

Comment: True, False  эквивалентны 1, 0. True == 1, False == 0

Comment: Оператор ``==`` проверяет равенство, а не эквивалентность. Сделайте теперь ``True is 1``. А во-вторых, True/False намного нагляднее и понятнее, чем 1/0.

Comment: Все равно пример работает, и это самое важное

Comment: Немного ранее я оставил аналогичный ответ и автор сказал мне: "Задача была в том, чтобы найти два двузначных числа, чье произведение равняется 9009".

Comment: Теперь все понятно. По сути вопрос не соответствует описанию.

Comment: спасибо! Помогло